# ipconfig \all, not working on linux fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, ifconfig

I am new to linux. I am trying to run "ifconfig" on linux fedora. It is working but when I run "ifconfig \all" or "ifconfig /flushdns",it gives me error i.e. "device not find", even if i try as super user.

Comment: you are not working with batch so do not try to use that commands, read this before to start http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php

Comment: Its worth learning to use  `ip` instead. ifconfig is depreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`ifconfig` on Linux is not the same as `ipconfig` on Windows. It will not take the same command line arguments. To learn more, try `ifconfig --help` and `man ifconfig` (*in fact, you can use `--help` and `man` with virtually **every** Linux command)!*

The error you're getting is because the commands interpret `\all` or `/flushdns` as device names, and there are no devices with those names, therefore the warning.

To get information about all network devices, just perform `ifconfig` without any other arguments.

To flush your DNS cache, there isn't a single, unified way. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/414842/110157) might help.

Comment: If any given command doesn't support the POSIX `--help`, it will almost certianly support `-h` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Probably what you want is `ifconfig -a` to see different interfaces, gateway information etc.

Answer (score -1):

I think you better issue this command on your console:

info ifconfig

To flush DNS on linux:

service nscd restart or service nscd reload